# Почему в list() TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: python, строки, list

Какая-то проблема с **list()**, когда я его использую на сетнутом списке (**set()**) по-сути в метод list() подаётся значение {'1', '2'}.
Ошибка:
`subject_list = sorted(list(set(db['subjects'].value + subject_list))) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. (Платформа - repl.it)
Вот кусок кода который используется:

```
if ',' in text:
    subject_list = text.title().strip().split(',')
else:
    subject_list = [text.title()]
    for subject in subject_list:
        if len(subject) < 1:
            send_message('Минимальная длина предмета - 1')
            continue
        if len(subject_list) > 24:  
            send_message('Слишком много значений!\n Максимальная длина списка - 24')
            continue
        print(set(db['subjects'].value + subject_list)) # output - {'1', '2'}
        subject_list = sorted(list(set(db['subjects'].value + subject_list)))
        db['subjects'] = subject_list
        list = subject_list
        list = '\n'.join(map(str, subject_list))
        send_message('Записано!\n' + list)
```

Comment: Вы переопределили символ `list`. Теперь это строка, не конструктор списков.

Comment: StanislavVolodarskiy, но если проверить `set(db['subjects'].value + subject_list)`, то там не строка, а множество.

Comment: Согласен с вами. А `list` теперь строка и вызывать `list(...)` нельзя.

Comment: а в каком месте `list` хотя бы раз вызывается перед list()? Ведь там где subject_list это только название переменной... Не понимаю в какой момент list стал `str`

Comment: Вот тут: `list = subject_list`. На первом проходе всё в порядке, на следующих проходах - ошибка.

Comment: ААА, это же всё в цикле! (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞
я и забыл, но я и не знал что такое может случится с list()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проходя по циклу **for**

```
for subject in subject_list:
```

в первый раз все работает правильно(**list** выполняется как функция)

```
subject_list = sorted(list(set(db['subjects'].value + subject_list)))
```

дальше вы задаете переменную **list**

```
list = subject_list
```

и на второй проход цикла **for**, **list** работает не как функция, а как переменная